# Argument Exception (Path is not of a legal form)

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, argumentexception

Background Infomation: I am using FileSystemWatcher class implemented in a service to monitor changes in the files. Heres the section of coding that throws an Argument Exception (Path is not a legal form) when the onCreate event is triggered.

`FileMonitor.CS`

```
public partial class FileMonitor:ServiceBase
{
 public FileSystemWatcher Watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    Private void FileWatcher()
    {
    FileActionHandler ActionHandler = new FileActionHandler();
    Watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(ActionHandler.onCreate);
    Watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(ActionHandler.onDelete);
    Watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(ActionHandler.onRenamed);
    Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
}
```

`FileActionHandler.CS`

```
 class FileActionHandler
 {
  FileMonitor FileMon = new FileMonitor();
  public void onCreate/onRename/onDelete(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {
       FileMon.Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
      }
      catch
      {
       /* Exception Code */
      }
      finally
      {
       FileMon.Watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Question:
Can anyone advice me on why is the exception being thrown and how I can go about resolving it ?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Thats the problem. I dont know which line throws the exception. But I narrowed down to this section of the code which resulted in the exception being thrown.

Comment: I'm guessing you have simplified your code before posting it here.can you post your actual code?

Comment: My actual entire code works fine while I use the FileSystemWatcher to monitor changes in the file. But ever since I added this section of the code, exception was being thrown and my service would stop working. Somewhere in this section throws the error.

Comment: Can you connect a debugger to the service to see where it's falling over?

Comment: Could you check if my coding is appropriate ? Like the use of objects from one class to another.

Comment: Hmm at first glance it looks alright. Have you tried debugging by logging to files? E.g. print exception stacktrace to a file? When is "FileWatcher()" called btw?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same issue when I did mine a few weeks ago. 
What I found was that you need to set the path before you set anything else.
So, right after you declare the object:

```
FileSystemWatcher watchfolder = new FileSystemWatcher();
watchfolder.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MonitorPath"];
```

You can read more here:
[Create a file watcher service for windows](http://www.devtoolcafe.com/dtc/howto/57/create-a-file-watcher-service-for-windows.aspx)

I hope this helps

Comment: Any Idea How Do I Incorporate Multi-Threading For Event Handlers ?

Comment: I havent done any multi threading with the file watcher services specifically...sorry :(

Comment: MultiThreading / Async could be done with TPL. Seach for ActionBlock.

Comment: Can't believe you had to set that property first, but it fixed it for me!

Comment: Found that as long as I don't set EnableRaisingEvents to true before I set Path, I'm fine.